# Notepad++ How to tell Macro to change 2 lines at a time?

Tags: macros, notepad++

With Notepad++, is it possible to create a "single" Macro that will change every 2 lines in a document? for example if I have the following text in a document...

```
Animal Care Technologies
    1112    Teachers’ World
Animal Health International
    2701
```

I would like to have this turned into...

```
<h4>Animal Care Technologies</h4>
    1112    Teachers’ World<br><br>
<h4>Animal Health International<h4>
    2701<br><br>
...etc...
```

Is it possible to do this this for every 2 lines within "one" Macro?  So far I am able to make the process work, but it requires me to use 2 Macros...one for the `<h4>` process, and a second marco to place the `<br><br>`.

Thanks for any advice on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If your document has the format you are talking about** then do the following:

1. Click at any character on the first line
2. Click the red "**recording**" button
3. Press the "**HOME**" button on your keyboard
4. Type `<h4>`
5. Press the "**END**" button on your keyboard
6. Type `</h4>`
7. Press the "**DOWN ARROW**" button on your keyboard
8. Press the "**END**" button on your keyboard
9. Type `<br><br>`
10. Click the "**Stop recording**" button
11. **Delete everything that you typed** (the h4 and the br tags)
12. Click on the first line
13. Click the "**Play**" button and select "**Until the end of the file**"

You're done!

Comment: John I would give you a grammy if you I could!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: With the same pattern you can create any macro you like, it's very useful when you need something to be repeated all over the document